# Can I apply CSS pseudo classes to just one link rather then all of them?

Tags: html, css

```
<a href = "www.fashjdkjdasfh.com">fashjdkjdasfh.com</a>
<a href = "www.hjdshf.com">hjdshf</a>
```

How would I go about making one of those links a different color then the other in my CSS document?

Comment: Do you want this link to have different colors for all its individual pseudo-class states as well?

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend number 12 from [here (The 30 CSS selectors you must memorize)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Basically you can search the `href` object for a string.

**HTML**

```
<a href = "www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href = "www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    color:green;
}

a [href*="google"] {
    color:red;
}
```

The above link is a GREAT article about CSS selectors and goes into depth with examples of many different selectors including the pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use Id attribute in  tag. By doing you can add extended CSS properties for that specific hyperlink.

```
<style>
  .a { ... }
  .a#myid { color:red; ... }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a class and assign the CSS accordingly:

```
<a href="http://www.fashjdkjdasfh.com">fashjdkjdasfh.com</a>
<a href="http://www.hjdshf.com" class="redlink">hjdshf</a>

<style>
  .redlink { color: red; }
</style>
```

BTW, I'd use `http` in your href or alternatively `//`.

http://www.stackoverflow.com
or
//www.stackoverflow.com

Good luck.